# How do you create fork processes for an entire node application?

Tags: node.js

I am wondering if wrapping the else brackets around the instantiation and the listen in the main js file of a node application is enough to create forks for the entire node application. It's usually not well explained, and involve simple code, so I was wondering if the following would work:

https://medium.com/the-andela-way/scaling-out-with-node-clusters-1dca4a39a2a

I looked at the blog post and it seems to imply that the forks are created for the entire application, but I am wondering if the code would only work for the get action defined in the code.

The rest comes from this github repo: https://github.com/gothinkster/node-express-realworld-example-app/blob/master/app.js

The application has other routes defined elsewhere and I was wondering if the code shown would work for the other routes in the other files, and what code needs to be wrapped in order for it to work as expected.

```
if (cluster.isMaster) {
    const cpuCount = os.cpus().length
    for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i++) {
        cluster.fork()
    }
}
else {
    var app = express();

    app.use(cors());

    // Normal express config defaults
    app.use(require('morgan')('dev'));
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
    app.use(bodyParser.json());

    app.use(require('method-override')());
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

    app.use(session({ secret: 'conduit', cookie: { maxAge: 60000 }, resave: false, saveUninitialized: false  }));

    if (!isProduction) {
      app.use(errorhandler());
    }

    if(isProduction){
      mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI);
    } else {
      mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/conduit');
      mongoose.set('debug', true);
    }

    require('./models/User');
    require('./models/Article');
    require('./models/Comment');
    require('./config/passport');

    app.use(require('./routes'));

    /// catch 404 and forward to error handler
    app.use(function(req, res, next) {
      var err = new Error('Not Found');
      err.status = 404;
      next(err);
    });

    /// error handlers

    // development error handler
    // will print stacktrace
    if (!isProduction) {
      app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
        console.log(err.stack);

        res.status(err.status || 500);

        res.json({'errors': {
          message: err.message,
          error: err
        }});
      });
    }

    // production error handler
    // no stacktraces leaked to user
    app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
      res.status(err.status || 500);
      res.json({'errors': {
        message: err.message,
        error: {}
      }});
    });

    // finally, let's start our server...
    var server = app.listen( process.env.PORT || 3000, function(){
      console.log('Listening on port ' + server.address().port);
    });

}
```

I am expecting the node application to spawn forks for all of the routes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes

That's the correct way to do it. You need some requires in that code but that's the main idea.

```
if isMaster 
   cluster.fork()
else 
   require('standalone.js')
```

You can easily verify it by running the script, you should see several logs instead of just one.

Comment: I was wondering if it would work for all the routes, but because it instantiates an express instance and uses the routes with app.use(require('./routes')); I am thinking it should work as expected. Thanks.